# Drupal Views Has Taxonomy Term with multiple terms

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

Good Morning,

I am developing an website and i am in a struggle to resolve this:

I have a link like this: mywebsite.com/aliments/fruit/banana.

And in a View that creates the page aliments i want only to show terms with fruit and banana checked at the same time.

My taxonomy terms are like this way:

Fruit

```
-Banana

-Apple
```

Fish

```
-Sardine
```

And so on...

So i have the tag Fruit and banana checked at the same time.

Some how i can't do it, if someone can help me.

Thanks,
Pedro Dias

Answer (score 4):

From the `manage view` page, go to section `Filter criteria` and click `Add`.

Then choose `Content: Has taxonomy term` and choose the vocabulary and the both terms you wanna use.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: First thank you for the answer @Muhammad Reda! My question was to search like in a recursive way the first argument IE is fruit and then the next would be banana, like this /fruit/banana but if i do that it will catch any banana from the terms i only want the banana that is children of the fruit, because my vocabulary has more than one repeated element.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform Validation on a Taxonomy Argument (Contextual Filter) to make sure it is part of a Vocabulary.

I would make the path of the view Ailments/Fruit/%

If you have other Vocabularies, make each one Ailments/Foo/% and Ailments/Bar/%

You can use the views Displays to share some of the features between all these views if you need to.